# Running django-admin tutorial erros: no module named django

Tags: django, windows, cmd

I just started to try and install/run Django on my cmd prompt and faced this issue although environment variables are set up for Django.

Besides getting a solution, can someone help me understand the root cause of the error below?

```
C:\Python>django-admin startproject test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\windows\syswow64\scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Comment: Have you installed Django before ?

Comment: I think you should try that command after make virtualenv, activate and install django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python based project it is always good to create Virtual Environment and then run your django program .

```
 pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
 mkvirtualenv test
 workon test
```

this will activate your virtual environment

Now install django

```
pip install django
```

After django installation complets

run

```
django-admin --version
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

On windows, go where you want to create your project, and call from there the django-admin.exe:
`path\to\django-admin.exe startproject project_name`

Its not a clean solution but worked for me.

Comment: not sure what the issue is, but i have been able to get around this by initiating the virtualenv before using django. worked for multiple projects.